# Modules in IOS with Air app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

We have a problem in our company with an application and would like to advise us an optimal solution, the point is that we have an application for tablets made with Flex mobile, our application can open modules in execution time downloading it from a server, these modules are opened perfectly with AIR or Android but in IOS is not possible, that's not working. Some solutions for us to have the extra functionality that provide these modules have occurred, are as follows:
1. Create a library for each extra functionality of each client and import all of them in the main application project.
2. Create a unique library with the functionality of all clients and then, import it in the main application project.
3. Create as many native extensions (ANE) and functionalities as are required by our different customer and import them into our application.
I would like to know which solution is optimal because in the future we can get 100 customers and maybe too much functionality may slow down the application.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Search Google - everything must be bundled inside your app - you cannot download and execute code later on (only assets).

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow dynamic linking at runtime. Modules are executable code and need to be bundled at build time, only then they can be loaded from the bundle.
Otherwise you could circumvent the AppStore and add any, potentially harmful code at execution time.